# Representing and working with polynomials in Python where coefficients can be variables

Tags: python, numpy, math, polynomials

I need to work with polynomials that are for the most part simple single-variable functions, however sometimes I need the coefficients to be expressed as an extra variable.

An example should make it clearer: For instance, I should be able to perform multiplication between the functions functions

`f(x) = 2x^2 + x`

`g(x) = ux^2 + x`

NumPy has convenient functions and classes to work with polynomials, however they can't represent variables as coefficients from what I've seen.

Is there another library that can handle this?

Comment: Have you tried `sympy`? You can define polynomials in sympy https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/polys/reference.html

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki looks promising, I'll try it with that